If the domain of $f(x)$ is $(-3, 1)$, then what is the domain of $f(\ln x)$?
I need a clear explanation for this question:

If the domain of $f(x)$ is $(-3, 1)$ then the domain of $f(\ln x)$ is ...
a) $\;(e^{-1}, e^3)$ 
b) $\;(0, \infty)$ 
c) $\;(1, \infty)$ 
d) $\;(e^{-3}, e^1)$

As we know, any logarithmic function has a domain of $(0, \infty)$, but the answer suggested that the domain should be $(e^{-3}, e^1)$. Why is this the case?

$\ln(x)$ and $f(\ln x)$ are not the same function, so they do not necessarily have the same domain.

I will just clear your doubt and you can solve it on your own.
The domain of $ln(x)$ is not equal to the domain of the function $f(ln(x))$
Now you can try it.
Hint : $lnx$ should have the values -3,1
Solution:

 Given $f(x)$ has a domain (-3,1), $f(x)$ is valid only when the values of x are in the range (-3,1).
So for the function $f(ln(x))$ to be valid $lnx$ should have the values in the range (-3,1) therefore the domain of the function $f(ln(x))$ should be $(e^{-3},e^{1})$


Hello, I think the hint is sufficient. Could you modify your answer so that it does not give the entire solution please ? Thank you !

Done changed it
